# Understanding "Monad m" in >>=

Tags: haskell, monads

Looking at Haskell's bind:

```
Prelude> :t (>>=)
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

I was confused by the following example:

```
Prelude> let same x = x

Prelude> [[1]] >>= \x -> same x
[1]
```

Looking at `>>=`'s signature, how does `\x -> same x` type check with `a -> m b`?

I would've expected `\x -> same x` to have produced a `[b]` type, since the `Monad m` type here is `[]`, as I understand.

Answer (score 9):

You say

> I would've expected `\x -> same x` to have produced a `[b]` type, since the `Monad m` type here is `[]`, as I understand.

and so it does because it is.

We have

```
[[1]] >>= \ x -> same x
=
[[1]]       >>=    \ x -> x
[[Int]]          [Int] -> [Int]        :: [Int]
[] [Int]         [Int] -> [] Int       :: [] Int
m  a             a        m  b            m  b
```

Sometimes `[]` is describing a kind of "nondeterminism" effect. Other times, `[]` is describing a container-like data structure. The fact that it's difficult to tell the difference between which of these two purposes is being served is a feature of which some people are terribly proud. I'm not ready to agree with them, but I see what they're doing.

Comment: `[]` is a container like data structure. The tuple `([], >>=, return)` is a different structure (which is implemented as a type class in Haskell) which can be used to model non determinism.

Answer (score 8):

> Looking at `>>=`'s signature, how does `\x -> same x` type check with `a -> m b`?

It's actually very simple. Look at the type signatures:

```
same       :: x -> x

(>>=)      :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

(>>= same) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
                                |________|
                                    |
                                 x -> x
```

Therefore:

```
x := a

-- and

x := m b

-- and by transitivity

a := x := m b

-- or

a := m b
```

Hence:

```
(>>= same) :: Monad m => m (m b) -> m b
```

This is just the `join` function from the `Control.Monad` module, and for the list monad it is the same as the `concat` function. Thus:

```
[[1]] >>= \x -> same x

-- is the same as the following via eta reduction

[[1]] >>= same

-- is the same as

(>>= same) [[1]]

-- is the same as

join [[1]]

-- is the same as

concat [[1]]

-- evaluates to

[1]
```

> I would've expected `\x -> same x` to have produced a `[b]` type, since the `Monad m` type here is `[]`, as I understand.

Indeed, it does. The `\x -> same x` function which has the type `x -> x` is specialized to the type `[b] -> [b]` as I explained above. Hence, `(>>= same)` is of the type `[[b]] -> [b]` which is the same as the `concat` function. It flattens a list of lists.

The `concat` function is a specialization of the `join` function which flattens a nested monad.

---

It should be noted that a monad can be defined in terms of either `>>=` or `fmap` and `join`. To [quote Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#fmap_and_join):

> Although Haskell defines monads in terms of the `return` and `>>=` functions, it is also possible to define a monad in terms of `return` and two other operations, `join` and `fmap`. This formulation fits more closely with the original definition of monads in category theory. The `fmap` operation, with type `Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`, takes a function between two types and produces a function that does the “same thing” to values in the monad. The `join` operation, with type `Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`, “flattens” two layers of monadic information into one.
>
> The two formulations are related as follows:
>
> ```
> fmap f m = m >>= (return . f)
> join n   = n >>= id
>
> m >>= g  ≡ join (fmap g m)
> ```
>
> Here, `m` has the type `Monad m => m a`, `n` has the type `Monad m => m (m a)`, `f` has the type `a -> b`, and `g` has the type `Monad m => a -> m b`, where `a` and `b` are underlying types.
>
> The `fmap` function is defined for any functor in the category of types and functions, not just for monads. It is expected to satisfy the functor laws:
>
> ```
> fmap id      ≡ id
> fmap (f . g) ≡ (fmap f) . (fmap g)
> ```
>
> The `return` function characterizes pointed functors in the same category, by accounting for the ability to “lift” values into the functor. It should satisfy the following law:
>
> ```
> return . f ≡ fmap f . return
> ```
>
> In addition, the `join` function characterizes monads:
>
> ```
> join . fmap join     ≡ join . join
> join . fmap return   ≡ join . return = id
> join . fmap (fmap f) ≡ fmap f . join
> ```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

As a few people have commented, you've found a really cute property about monads here. For reference, let's look at the signature for bind:

```
:: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

In your case, the type `a === m b` as you have a `[[a]]` or `m (m a)`. So, if you rewrite the signature of the above bind operation, you get:

```
:: Monad m => m (m b) -> ((m b) -> m b) -> m b
```

I mentioned that this is cute, because by extension, this works for *any* nested monad. e.g.

```
:: [[b]] -> ([b] -> [b]) -> [b]
:: Maybe (Maybe b) -> (Maybe b -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
:: Reader (Reader b) -> (Reader b -> Reader b) -> Reader b
```

If you look at the function that get's applied here, you'll see that it's the identity function (e.g. `id`, `same`, `:: forall a. a -> a`).

This is included in the standard libraries for Haskell, as `join`. You can [look at the source here on hackage.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#join%20Hackage) You'll see it's implemented as `bind id`, or `\mma -> mma >>= id`, or `(=<<) id`

Answer (score 1):

As you say `m` is `[]`. Then `a` is `[Integer]` (ignoring the fact that numbers are polymorphic for simplicity's sake) and `b` is `Integer`. So `a -> m b` becomes `[Integer] -> [Integer]`.

Answer (score 1):

First: we should use the standard version of `same`, it is called `id`.

Now, let's rename some type variables

```
id :: (a'' ~ a) => a -> a''
```

What this means is: the signature of `id` is that of a function mapping between two types, with the extra constraint that both types be equal. That's all – we do not require any particular properties, like “being flat”.

Why the hell would I write it this way? Well, if we also rename some of the variables in the bind signature...

```
(>>=) :: (Monad m, a'~m a, a''~m b) => a' -> (a -> a'') -> a''
```

...then it is obvious how we can plug the `id`, as the type variables have already been named accordingly. The type-equality constraint `a''~a` from `id` is simply taken to the compound's signature, i.e.

```
(>>=id) :: (Monad m, a'~m a, a''~m b, a''~a) => a' -> a''
```

or, simplifying that,

```
(>>=id) :: (Monad m, a'~m a, m b~a) => a' -> m b
(>>=id) :: (Monad m, a'~m (m b))    => a' -> m b
(>>=id) :: (Monad m)                => m (m b) -> m b
```

So what this does is, it flattens a nested monad to a single application of that same monad. Quite simple, and as a matter of fact this is one the “more fundamental” operation: mathematicians [don't define the bind operator, they instead define](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28category_theory%29#Formal_definition) two morphisms `η :: a -> m a` (we know that, it's `return`) and `μ :: m (m a) -> m a` – yup, that's the one you've just discovered. In Haskell, it's called [`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join).

Answer (score 0):

The monad here is `[a]` and the example is pointlessly complicated. This’ll be clearer:

```
Prelude> [[1]] >>= id
[1]
```

just as

```
Prelude> [[1]] >>= const [2]
[2]
```

i.e. `>>=` is `concatMap` and is `concat` when used with `id`.